# Validation in Winform using Data Annotations

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I create a validating class like so:

```
public interface IDataErrorInfo
{
    string this[string columnName] { get; }
    string Error { get; }
}

public class BaseModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
   [Browsable(false)]
   public string this[string property]
    {
        get
        {
            var propertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[property];
            if (propertyDescriptor == null)
                return string.Empty;

            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(
                                      propertyDescriptor.GetValue(this),
                                      new ValidationContext(this, null, null)
                                      { MemberName = property },
                                      results);
            if (!result)
                return results.First().ErrorMessage;
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var result = Validator.TryValidateObject(this,
                new ValidationContext(this, null, null), results, true);
            if (!result)
                return string.Join("\n", results.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created a class with data annotation like so

```
public class ReaderSetting : BaseModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("RfidAddress")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "RFID Address is required.")]
    [StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Max Length is 3")]
    public string RfidAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Then I tried this out like this:

```
private void btnAddSetting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var readerSetting = new ReaderSetting();
    try
    {
        readerSetting.RfidAddress = txtRfidAddress.Text; // txtRfidAddress.Text is blank
    }
    catch (ValidationException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    _readerSettingList.Add(readerSetting);
    var source = new BindingSource();
    source.DataSource = _readerSettingList;
    dgRfidSettings.DataSource = source;
}
```

How come it doesn't pass through the ValidationException?

Comment: The attribute doesn't change the behaviour of the property itself. You need code to invoke the attribute. Things like the ASP.NET MVC model binder and EF will do that because they were coded to do that. WinForms data-binding doesn't include such functionality but it wouldn't matter even if it did in your case because you're just straight setting the property, which is not WinForms specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following might work for you.

Try it out on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/loyVoO).

```
public class ReaderSetting
{
    [JsonPropertyName("RfidAddress")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "RFID Address is required.")]
    [StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Max Length is 3")]
    public string RfidAddress { get; set; }
}

public class EntityValidationResult
{
    public IList<ValidationResult> Errors { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid => Errors.Count == 0;
    public EntityValidationResult(IList<ValidationResult> errors = null)
    {
        Errors = errors ?? new List<ValidationResult>();
    }
}
public class EntityValidator<T> where T : class
{
    public EntityValidationResult Validate(T entity)
    {
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var vc = new ValidationContext(entity, null, null);
        Validator.TryValidateObject(entity, vc, validationResults, true);

        return new EntityValidationResult(validationResults);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
ReaderSetting readerSetting = new() { RfidAddress = "abcd" };
EntityValidator<ReaderSetting> validator = new EntityValidator<ReaderSetting>();
EntityValidationResult result = validator.Validate(readerSetting);
if (result.IsValid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Valid");
}
else
{
    result.Errors.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ErrorMessage));
}
```

Comment: This is what I actually did to make it work. Thank you anyways. I would still mark this as the right answer.